# Moving files but retaining tabbles

Tags: filesystems, file-management

I've started using tabbles for file management.  Unfortunately after tagging well over 100 files I discovered that as soon as I move the file it loses all of it's tags!

Is there any way to configure/use tabbles to retain the tags when the file is moved?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you need to move the file within Tabbles in order to maintain the tags.  This is covered in the product [manual wiki](http://tabbles.net/manuals-wiki/)

Comment: mmm, I tried that, but maybe there's a trick to it or something.  Thanks!